# Ubuntu doesn't seen to recognize language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language

New here, so sorry for any mistake...

Long story short:
 I live in Brazil, so need to use portuguese language, but my keyboard is US layout. I was using Ubuntu 19.04 and the layout was something like "Portuguese (Brazil, int. alt.)", and it was a perfect match.

Few days ago I updated the system to 19.10 and this layout has vanished from options, so I searched internet a little and re-created it. The moment I did it worked flawlessly, until I turned off the system. Now my Ubuntu does not recognize Portuguese. I'm using the US layout, but can't use any "latin signs".

Any guesses? Thanks!

Comment: That exact layout does not exist AFAIK. Possibly it's _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ you are after. Or maybe _Spanish (Latin American)_.

Comment: Yes, the US layout seens precise, however I can't use portuguese, like putting the "~" above "a", that seens to be the problem... using portuguese language, but with US layout

Comment: Holding <Shift> while pressing the key to the left of the <1> key gives you `dead_tilde`, and if you then press a you get ã. So it seems you just need to familiar yourself with the layout. :)

Comment: Hmm, got what you're saying, but I think it's not that... I've tried it and what happens is there are no _dead_ keys, I mean, if I hold <Shift> and press the key left of <1>, I get the ~ with no option tu put it on top of any letter. =(

Comment: I assumed you were using _English (US, intl. with dead keys)_. That's the keyboard layout you should use, I think. The basic _English (US)_ does not have dead keys.

Comment: Yes, I am, but without sucess, unfortunately.

Comment: What's the output of this command: `im-config -m`

Comment: It says:
default
ibus
ibus

ibus

Comment: A suggestion: Add a new user for test purposes to your system, log in as that user, and see if the issue is present for that user too.

Comment: Created a new user and the same issue happens in the new profile.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: So, I've checked and the problem seens to be that my keyboard does not change. I've added other languages (with completely different key disposition) and nothing happens, eve when they are selected.

Comment: It is unbelievable that this problem exists in Ubuntu 19.10.  I have been using Windows and OSX with US Keyboards and this has not been a problem for decades. The Gnome way of setting the keyboard layout is a mess, it makes no sense. I have to choose Portuguese and then US keyboard layout, wtf! One thing is the language, another the input keyboard layout. When I use Porguese ("native for american keyboards") the layout is all messed up, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I got a way to solve the problem. First of all, thanks Gunnar for your dedication haha.
So, the only way I could resolve it was:
 1 - I took another machine with Ubuntu 19.10 just installed and checked if it works.
 2 - I've made a copy of 3 files from the other machine and used overwrote in mine. They where: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pt.txt` and `/etc/boot/environment.d/90atk-adaptor.conf`
 *The first file, *evdev.xml*, tells the system all the existent keyboard layouts
 *The file *pt.txt*, is the configuration to all portuguese layouts
 *The file *90atk-adaptor.conf*, turns on the caracter "Ç" when pressing " ' " + "c"
 3 - Rebooted my laptop to aply changes

Now it works: ã á ç

Comment: Good that you figured it out. As regards ç you may want to take a look at the file `/etc/profile.d/cedilla-portuguese.sh` which is there by default.